# How to print any line in kotlin (out side any function)?

Tags: kotlin, global-variables

```
 println("Enter the number of rows:")
    val rows = readln().toInt()
 println("Enter the number of seats in each row:")
    val columns = readln().toInt()
 
    val cinema = MutableList(rows) { MutableList(columns) { 'S' } }

fun main() {

    choice()
}
fun choice() {
    println("Enter Choice:")
    val input = readln().toInt()
    println(input)
}
```

This shows an error in printing first two print commands Why?
Ide says need top level declaration

Comment: Why are you calling stuff outside of the main function? Why not create a private function, called in the main function, to perform the rows and columns print statements?

Comment: Someone correct me if I'm wrong, but I'm also pretty sure you can't call readln().toInt() outside of a function.

Comment: @MatthewS 
it is possible to call readln().toInt() outside main

Comment: Kotlin is not a scripting language and it doesn't allow an arbitrary code at the top level. (as long as we don't use a special scripting mode / `kts` files). What do you try to achieve, why do you need it outside of `main()`?

Answer (score 0):

This is a limit of the JVM. Every action must be inside *some* function. You could develop a language such that this function declaration / call is generated for you, but Kotlin (with .kt, regular Kotlin files) does not do this (.kts, scripting files, do support this).

As such, you must put every instruction inside a function. Do note though, that these function declarations can be top-level (outside of a class or companion) and relevantly exported to other files for usage.

Below is your code, fixed:

```
fun main() {
    println("yes")
    println("Enter the number of rows:")
    val rows = readln().toInt()
    println("Enter the number of seats in each row:")
    val columns = readln().toInt()
}
```

Comment: "You could develop a language such that this function declaration / call is generated for you, but Kotlin does not do this" It does, just not for `.kt` files. `.kts` files support toplevel imperative code.

Comment: @RaphaelTarita adjusted to include this! i've never used kts outside of gradle so had no clue this was an actual format you can use lol

Answer (score 0):

Kotlin does not support top-level imperative code in `.kt` files. At the topmost scope level, only declarations are allowed (things like functions, classes, values, typealiases, ...). the code that currently sits above your main function isn't contained in a function itself, therefore this will not compile. There are a few different things you can do to mitigate this:

1. Copy the code from outside of `main()` and put it into `main()`. That is rather easy and gets the job done.
2. Take the code that currently is on the top level and put it in a new function, something like `initCinema()` or similar. You'll have to think about what you want to do with your `cinema` variable, you probably want to return that from the function.
3. As opposed to what the other answer on this question is saying, Kotlin *does* support top-level imperative code, just not in regular `.kt` files. There is a feature called Kotlin Scripting, and it allows you to code in `.kts` files which *do* allow code like you've written it. I personally don't recommend using `.kts` files, but they can be useful for quick prototyping (you might also want to consider using a Jupyter Notebook with the Kotlin kernel). So, in short, if you change the file extension of the file you've written this code in from `.kt` to `.kts`, that would also make your code work.